# Detecting an intruder in WSN in Castalia simulator

Tags: simulation, omnet++

How will we detect an intruder in a WSN since there is no concept of sensing range in Castalia? How will the network sense an object that has entered the WSN field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as sensing range of sensing devices. There is only **sensing sensitivity** of the device (the signal threshold to trigger the transducer).

The so-called "sensing range" used in many early WSN papers is a poor abstraction of reality (which unfortunately proved to be long-lived). In order for this abstraction to make any sense we must make arbitrary and limiting assumptions about the *physical process* that triggers the sensing devices. For example, we must assume that the sources of signal of the physical process we are monitoring (i.e., the intruders in your scenario), all have the same power, and that the medium that allows the physical process signal to propagate does so in a uniform matter. In terms of abstractions, it is much better to think of the probability of sensing by a given sensing device. This depends on the sensitivity of the device, and also on the physical process (how powerful are the signal sources and how they propagate in the medium).

The situation is directly analogous to the so-called "radio transmission range". As the transmission disk model is a simplistic (and usually poor) communications model, the disk sensing range model is similarly simplistic. I suggest you steer clear of such poor abstractions.

I am not sure why you think you need the concept of sensing range to detect an intruder. Castalia models sensing devices and it models physical processes. So a sensing device can be triggered by something happening in the environment. A very simple intrusion model would be that if a sensing device senses a signal above a certain threshold you can say that an intruder was detected. More complex models would require multiple nodes to detect a signal, but that's up to you and how your particular intrusion scenario looks like.

Read section 4.5 and 4.6 of the [Castalia User's manual](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia) to get a better understanding of Castalia's sensing abstractions. You can also see the Bridge Test simulation scenario to get a taste of something similar to what you want. In that scenario, you have cars driving on a bridge. All nodes sense the cars as they pass near them. There is no question of intrusion detection in that scenario, but you can see how the physical process can be set to model something like intruders.

Comment: I understand that i don't need sensing range for intruder detection. I also have to ensure the full coverage of WSN i.e, network is fully monitored by nodes. Coverage is defined as union of sensing ranges of all sensor nodes. How can i implement this in Castalia?

Comment: I am basically considering the scenario that if a car is in WSN, it should be in the sensing vicinity of atleast one node at any given time. It should not go unnoticed at any point in time.

Comment: I am not sure you understand you don't need sensing range, since you continue by writing "coverage is defined as union of sensing ranges". Study the sensing models that Castalia is using, make sure you understand why they are more realistic than the abstractions of "sensing range" and "coverage" and you could adapt your problem to use them.

Comment: In case I want to implement sensing range because I already have developed an algorithm that I have to implement, is there any way to do that?
like there is an equation from which we can calculate transmission range.

Comment: I already mentioned in my answer the limiting assumptions on the physical process that would allow the abstraction of sensing range to make some sense. "For example, we must assume that the sources of signal..."

Comment: yes, i can utilize sensing sensitivity. is sensing sensitivity implemented in Castalia?

Comment: i got it, device sensitivity is implemented in Castalia. How can i use this parameter to calculate sensing range?

Comment: Study Castalia's model as I suggested in my answer. If you have further questions, ask a separate question in stackoverflow. The comments are only for clarifications on the answer.

Comment: I have asked a separate question. link to the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686680/calculating-sensing-range-from-sensing-sensitivity-of-the-device-in-castalia