# Calculating sensing range from sensing sensitivity of the device in Castalia?

Tags: wireless, omnet++

I am implementing a WSN algorithm in Castalia. I need to calculate sensing range of the sensing device. I know I will need to use the sensing sensitivity parameter but what will be the exact equation?

Comment: The response you get from the SensorManager depends entirely on the PhysicalProcess module used. What PhysicalProcess are you using? What kind of sensor are you trying to simulate?

Comment: i am implementing an object tracking protocol so i might be using carphysicalprocess. there will only be one object inside the network at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer will vary depending on the behaviour specified by the PhysicalProcess module used. Since you say in your comment that you may be using the CarsPhysicalProcess let's use that as an example.

A sensor reading request initiated by the application is first sent to the SensorManager via a `SensorReadingMessage` message. In `SensorManager.cc` you can see how this is processed in its `handleMessage` function:

```
...
case SENSOR_READING_MESSAGE: {
    SensorReadingMessage *rcvPacket =check_and_cast<SensorReadingMessage*>(msg);
    int sensorIndex = rcvPacket->getSensorIndex();

    simtime_t currentTime = simTime();
    simtime_t interval = currentTime - sensorlastSampleTime[sensorIndex];
    int getNewSample = (interval < minSamplingIntervals[sensorIndex]) ? 0 : 1;

    if (getNewSample) { //the last request for sample was more than minSamplingIntervals[sensorIndex] time ago
        PhysicalProcessMessage *requestMsg =
            new PhysicalProcessMessage("sample request", PHYSICAL_PROCESS_SAMPLING);
        requestMsg->setSrcID(self); //insert information about the ID of the node
        requestMsg->setSensorIndex(sensorIndex);    //insert information about the index of the sensor
        requestMsg->setXCoor(nodeMobilityModule->getLocation().x);
        requestMsg->setYCoor(nodeMobilityModule->getLocation().y);

        // send the request to the physical process (using the appropriate 
        // gate index for the respective sensor device )
        send(requestMsg, "toNodeContainerModule", corrPhyProcess[sensorIndex]);

        // update the most recent sample times in sensorlastSampleTime[]
        sensorlastSampleTime[sensorIndex] = currentTime;
    } else {    // send back the old sample value

        rcvPacket->setSensorType(sensorTypes[sensorIndex].c_str());
        rcvPacket->setSensedValue(sensorLastValue[sensorIndex]);
        send(rcvPacket, "toApplicationModule");
        return;
    }
    break;
}
....
```

As you can see, what it's doing is first working out how much time has elapsed since the last sensor reading request for this sensor. If it's less time than specified by the minSamplingInterval possible for this sensor (this is determined by the maxSampleRates NED parameter of the SensorManager), it just returns the last sensor reading given. If it's greater, a new sensor reading is made.

A new sensor reading is made by sending a `PhysicalProcessMessage` message to the PhysicalProcess module (via the `toNodeContainerModule` gate). In the message we pass the X and Y coordinates of the node.

Now, if we have specified CarsPhysicalProcess as the physical process to be used in our omnetpp.ini file, the `CarsPhysicalProcess` module will receive this message. You can see this in `CarsPhysicalProcess.cc`:

```
....
case PHYSICAL_PROCESS_SAMPLING: {
    PhysicalProcessMessage *phyMsg = check_and_cast < PhysicalProcessMessage * >(msg);

    // get the sensed value based on node location
    phyMsg->setValue(calculateScenarioReturnValue(
        phyMsg->getXCoor(), phyMsg->getYCoor(), phyMsg->getSendingTime()));
    // Send reply back to the node who made the request
    send(phyMsg, "toNode", phyMsg->getSrcID());
    return;
}
...
```

You can see that we calculate a sensor value based on the X and Y coordinates of the node, and the time at which the sensor reading was made. The response is sent back to the SensorManager via the `toNode` gate. So we need to look at the `calculateScenarioReturnValue` function to understand what's going on:

```
double CarsPhysicalProcess::calculateScenarioReturnValue(const double &x_coo,
                    const double &y_coo, const simtime_t &stime)
{
    double retVal = 0.0f;
    int i;
    double linear_coeff, distance, x, y;

    for (i = 0; i < max_num_cars; i++) {
        if (sources_snapshots[i][1].time >= stime) {
            linear_coeff = (stime - sources_snapshots[i][0].time) /
                (sources_snapshots[i][1].time - sources_snapshots[i][0].time);
            x = sources_snapshots[i][0].x + linear_coeff * 
                (sources_snapshots[i][1].x - sources_snapshots[i][0].x);
            y = sources_snapshots[i][0].y + linear_coeff * 
                (sources_snapshots[i][1].y - sources_snapshots[i][0].y);
            distance = sqrt((x_coo - x) * (x_coo - x) +
             (y_coo - y) * (y_coo - y));
            retVal += pow(K_PARAM * distance + 1, -A_PARAM) * car_value;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

We start with a sensor return value of 0. Then we loop over every car that is on the road (if you look at the `TIMER_SERVICE` case statement in the `handleMessage` function, you will see that CarsPhysicalProcess puts cars on the road randomly according to the `car_interarrival` rate, up to a maximum of `max_num_cars` number of cars). For every car, we calculate how far the car has travelled down the road, and then calculate the distance between the car and the node. Then for each car we add to the return value based on the formula:

```
pow(K_PARAM * distance + 1, -A_PARAM) * car_value
```

Where `distance` is the distance we have calculated between the car and the node, `K_PARAM = 0.1`, `A_PARAM = 1` (defined at the top of CarsPhysicalProcess.cc) and `car_value` is a number specified in the CarsPhysicalProcess.ned parameter file (default is 30).

This value is passed back to the SensorManager. The SensorManager then may change this value depending on the sensitivity, resolution, noise and bias of the sensor (defined as SensorManager parameters):

```
....
case PHYSICAL_PROCESS_SAMPLING:
{
    PhysicalProcessMessage *phyReply = check_and_cast<PhysicalProcessMessage*>(msg);
    int sensorIndex = phyReply->getSensorIndex();
    double theValue = phyReply->getValue();

    // add the sensor's Bias and the random noise 
    theValue += sensorBias[sensorIndex];
    theValue += normal(0, sensorNoiseSigma[sensorIndex], 1);

    // process the limitations of the sensing device (sensitivity, resoultion and saturation)
    if (theValue < sensorSensitivity[sensorIndex])
        theValue = sensorSensitivity[sensorIndex];
    if (theValue > sensorSaturation[sensorIndex])
        theValue = sensorSaturation[sensorIndex];

    theValue = sensorResolution[sensorIndex] * lrint(theValue / sensorResolution[sensorIndex]);
....
```

So you can see that if the value is below the sensitivity of the sensor, the floor of the sensitivity is returned.

So basically you can see that there is no specific 'sensing range' in Castalia - it all depends on how the specific PhysicalProcess handles the message. In the case of CarsPhysicalProcess, as long as there is a car on the road, it will always return a value, regardless of the distance - it just might be very small if the car is a long distance away from the node. If the value is very small, you may receive the lowest sensor sensitivity instead. You could increase or decrease the `car_value` parameter to get a stronger response from the sensor (so this is kind of like a sensor range)

**EDIT---**
The default sensitivity (which you can find in `SensorManager.ned`) is 0. Therefore for CarsPhysicalProcess, any car on the road at any distance should be detected and returned as a value greater than 0. In other words, there is an unlimited range. If the car is very, very far away it may return a number so small it becomes truncated to zero (this depends on the limits in precision of a double value in the implementation of c++)

If you wanted to implement a sensing range, you would have to set a value for `devicesSensitivity` in `SensorManager.ned`. Then in your application, you would test to see if the returned value is greater than the sensitivity value - if it is, the car is 'in range', if it is (almost) equal to the sensitivity it is out of range. I say **almost** because (as we have seen earlier) the SensorManager adds *noise* to the value returned, so for example if you have a sensitivity value of 5, and no cars, you will get values which will hover slightly around 5 (e.g. 5.0001, 4.99)

With a sensitivity value set, to calculate the sensing range (assuming only 1 car on the road), this means simply solving the equation above for distance, using the minimum sensitivity value as the returned value. i.e. if we use a sensitivity value of 5:

```
 5 = pow(K_PARAM * distance + 1, -A_PARAM) * car_value
```

Substitute values for the parameters, and use algebra to solve for distance.

Comment: you have described it very well. Thanks for explaining it in detail.
I want to take distance as a factor affecting the car value being received at sensor node.
i will have a fix sensitivity and a fix car value. i would like to calculate the maximum distance at which the sensor receives the value above the sensor sensitivity and that distance can be my sensing range. how can i do it? is there any equation i can use or i will have to do tests by moving the car away from sensor?

Comment: My algorithm relies heavily on the concept of sensing range. do you think castalia is a good option for that? or is there any other simulator better for implementing the concept of sensing range?

Comment: I've added a bit more to the end of my answer to explain further. By default, the sensitivity of sensors in SensorManager is zero, so any cars at any range will be detected (infinite range) because the value returned will be greater than zero. If you set the sensitivity to something greater than zero, use algebra to solve the equation given for distance

Comment: @ammararazzaq I suggest (at the very least) to accept James' extraordinarily detailed and enlightening answer! He went in the trouble to explain so much, even though your question showed very little effort.

Comment: yes I have. @Thanassis. sensing range was my biggest issue and it has been solved because of James.

Comment: Thanks @James your explanation has cleared so many doubts that I had regarding castalia and finally I can start implementing my algorithm.